# Angular2 Saving/Loading JSON to Local Storage

Tags: json, angular, local-storage, filereader

I'm trying to save and load data from a JSON file on a user's computer using Angular2. Basically I save a user's data to LocalStorage. I want to add a way for them to back up their data in case they need to clear their browser for some reason. I'm using HTML's File API to save/load. I can successfully write the JSON data from LocalStorage to file. However, when I try to reload the file back to LocalStorage, all the quotes end up with a backslash in front of it.

```
[{\"buildname\":\"\",\"unitname\":\"Jack\",\"id\":\"314\",\"rarity\":5,\"name_rarity\":\"jack-5\",\"createdOn\":\"2017-03-06T08:49:54.165Z\",\"totalHP\":2538,\"totalMP\":110,\"totalATK\":141}]
```

I'm trying to get it to save to LocalStorage like this:

```
[{"buildname":"","unitname":"Jack","id":"314","rarity":5,"name_rarity":"jack-5","createdOn":"2017-03-06T08:49:54.165Z","totalHP":2538,"totalMP":110,"totalATK":141}]
```

Heres my app.component.ts file:

```
builds = [];
      backUpData()
    {
      var textToSave = localStorage.getItem('builds');
      var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"octet/stream"});
      var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
      var fileNameToSaveAs = 'newsavetotext.json'
      var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
      downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
      downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
      downloadLink.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

      downloadLink.click();
    }

    changeListener($event) : void {
      this.loadData($event.target);
    }

    loadData(inputValue: any) {
      var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
      var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
      myReader.onloadend = function(e){
        localStorage.setItem('builds', JSON.stringify(myReader.result));
        console.log(myReader.result);
      }
      this.builds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('builds'));
      myReader.readAsText(file);
    }
```

My app.component.html:

```
<button type="button" name="button" (click)="backUpData()">Back Up Data</button>

<div>
  Select file: <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">
</div>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: where is this function (click)="`saveTextAsFile()`" in .ts which gets data from localStorage

Comment: local storage is not doing anything wrong here, as you can save/read the data firsttime perfectly, can you console out the data when you are reloading the data to local storage, as there i think it's messing up

Comment: Just renamed it to (click)="backUpData().